# R data.table: how to refer to current object in a chain?

Tags: r, data.table

In R's `data.table`, one can chain multiple operations by putting together squared braces, each of which will be able to use non-standard evaluation of e.g. column names for whatever is the current transformation in a chain - for example:

```r
dt[,
    .(agg1=mean(var1), agg2=mean(var2)),
    by=.(col1, col2)
][,
    .(agg2=ceiling(agg2), agg3=agg2^2)
]
```

Suppose I want to do an operation which involves computing some function that would take as input a `data.frame`, which I want to put in a data.table chain taking the **current** object in the chain, while using these results in e.g. a `by` clause. In `magrittr`/`dplyr` chains, I can use a `.` to refer to the object that is passed to a pipe and do arbitrary operations with it, but in `data.table` the chains work quite differently.

For example, suppose I have this table and I want to compute a percentage of total across groups:

```r
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(col1 = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), col2=10:15)
dt[, .(agg1 = sum(col2)/sum(dt$col2)), by=.(col1)]
```

```
   col1 agg1
1:    1 0.44
2:    2 0.36
3:    3 0.20
```

In this snippet, I referred to the full object name inside `[` to compute the total of the column as `sum(dt$col2)`, which bypasses the `by` part. But if it were in a chain and these columns were calculated through other operations, I wouldn't have been able to simply use `dt` like that as that's an external variable (that is, it's evaluated in an environment level outside the `[` scope).

How can I refer to the current object/table inside a chain? To be clear, **I am not asking about how to do this specific grouping operation**, but about a general way of accessing the current object so as to use it in arbitrary functions.

Comment: I mean a chain of square braces like `dt[op1][op2][op3]`.

Comment: Is the 'var1', 'var2', part of the original data

Comment: @akrun No, that's the issue.

Comment: But, your code block shows `dt[,
    .(agg1=mean(var1), agg2=mean(var2)),
    by=.(col1, col2)
]`

Comment: @akrun Sorry, edited it a bit.

Comment: In `.data.table`, the behavior is similar to transform in base R i.e. if you are trying to update a column within `.(`, it may not get the updated column i.e. ` .(agg2=ceiling(agg2), agg3=agg2^2)` you the `agg2^2` will be from the original `agg2` and not the `ceiling` one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `.SDcols` or directly `.SD` and select the column as a vector with `[[`

```
dt[, .(agg1 = sum(col2)/sum(dt$col2)), by=.(col1)][, 
       .(agg1 = ceiling(.SD[["agg1"]]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to create complex chains of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) expressions. One sample use case is *to compute a percentage of total across groups* in a chain like in

```
dt[, .(agg1 = sum(col2) / sum(dt$col2)), by = col1]
```

> ```
>    col1 agg1
> 1:    1 0.44
> 2:    2 0.36
> 3:    3 0.20
> ```

Here `col2` appears in two places. First, to compute the group totals, and second to compute the grand total.

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has a special symbol `.SD` which stands for ***S**ubset, **S**elfsame, or **S**elf-reference of the **D**ata* (please, see the [vignette *Using .SD for Data Analysis*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-sd-usage.html) for details and examples).

When used in grouping (`by =` ), `.SD` refers to the *subset* of the data within each group and thus cannot be used to refer to the whole (ungrouped) dataset. So,

```
data.table(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), col2 = 10:15)[
  , .(agg1 = sum(col2) / sum(.SD$col2)), by = col1]
```

returns the trivial result `1` for each group.

#### Chaining within a chain

However, I believe I have found a way to accomplish OP's goal by *chaining within a chain*:

```
data.table(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), col2 = 10:15)[
  , .SD[, .(agg1 = sum(col2)), by = col1][, .(col1, agg1 = agg1 / sum(col2))]]
```

> ```
>    col1 agg1
> 1:    1 0.44
> 2:    2 0.36
> 3:    3 0.20
> ```

Here,

```
data.table(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), col2 = 10:15)[, j]
```

is a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) chain with a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) created on-the-fly, i.e., without assigning to a variable name, and  with the `j` expression being another [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) chain

```
.SD[, .(agg1 = sum(col2)), by = col1][, .(col1, agg1 = agg1 / sum(col2))]
```

The *inner* chain consists of three parts:

1. `.SD` refers to the whole dataset.
2. The next expression computes the aggregates by group, returning a data.table with two columns, `col1` and `agg1`.
3. The last expression divides `agg1` by the grand total `sum(col2)`. As `col2` is *not* included in the result of step 2, it is taken from the whole dataset.

However, if you do not want to rely on scoping rules, we can achieve the same result by explicitely computing the grand total beforehand:

```
data.table(col1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), col2 = 10:15)[
  , {tmp <- sum(col2); .SD[, .(agg1 = sum(col2) / tmp), by = col1]}]
```

Here, we use the fact that in [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) `j` can be an arbitrary expression (enclosed in curly braces).